# GitHub Actions workflow deploy complaining about env variables

Tags: github-actions, azure-aks

I am running a deploy workflow for azure and getting the following error. any idea what is it complaining about

```
error: error validating "STDIN": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.imagePullSecrets[0]): unknown field "args" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.LocalObjectReference, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.imagePullSecrets[0]): unknown field "command" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.LocalObjectReference, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.imagePullSecrets[0]): unknown field "env" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.LocalObjectReference, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.imagePullSecrets[0]): unknown field "ports" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.LocalObjectReference, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.imagePullSecrets[0]): unknown field "volumeMounts" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.LocalObjectReference]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
90
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

It deployed the pod and the pod is stuck at this on AKS:

```bash
$ kubectl get po  
 
NAME                                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
 view-app-dev-895f4c475-mrmtj   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          4h14m


Events:
  Type    Reason   Age                       From     Message
  ----    ------   ----                      ----     -------
  Normal  Pulling  32m (x45 over 3h57m)      kubelet  Pulling image " view:latest"
  Normal  BackOff  2m23s (x1031 over 3h57m)  kubelet  Back-off pulling image " view:latest"
```

Comment: Can you share the workflow setup? Seems like a secret is missing that is needed to pull the image with? Is it a private container registry your are using?

Comment: I have created the secret into the namespace.                                                     NAME                            TYPE                                  DATA   AGE                            docker-registry-credentials     kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1      8h                imagePullSecrets:
          
        - name: docker-registry-credentials                                                                        its a private container registry

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I put the imagepullsecrets in the manifest file at the wrong place.

that fixed the issue.

imagepullsecrets should be below volume mounts not above